# How can I represent entity inheiritance as DTO if I want to use this DTO in service layer

Tags: java, spring, dto

Let's say I am having inheritance in my entities like:
Animal - parent
Childs:
Cat,
Dog

I would like to use DTOs in my service layer and I wonder how can I represent the inheritance above as DTO?
For example, I had a method like this in the service before using DTO: Animal add(Animal animal).
I would like to be something like this: AnimalDTO add(AnimalDTO team)

Comment: That is perfectly possible, just do it as you did for the entities. Or maybe I am not understanding your question.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the quick answer. I assume it's not a bad practice to be done and should work well. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is perfectly possible, just do it as you did for the entities.